# Accessing a ASPxButton in a DataItemTemplate in when row is bound

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a aspxgridview that shows a number of buttons for each row.  What I want to be able to do is enable some of these buttons on a per row basis, based on some background logic.  When the HtmlRowPrepared event is trapped I tru and use e.Row.FindControl("butApprove") but it returns null.  If I keep searching down through the Controls collection several times I can find the control with that id.

Is there an easier way of doing this as I am new to the DevExpress controls.

```
        <dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn VisibleIndex="4">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="butAddNote" runat="server" Text="Add Note"></dx:ASPxButton> 
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="butEditContact" runat="server" Text="Edit Contact"></dx:ASPxButton> 
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="butApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve"></dx:ASPxButton> 
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="butReject" runat="server" Text="Reject"></dx:ASPxButton> 
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataButtonEditColumn>
```

Many thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the [HtmlRowCreated](http://ms-help://DevExpress.NETv10.1/DevExpress.AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlRowCreatedtopic.htm) event and access buttons using the [ASPxGridView.FindRowCellTemplateControl](http://ms-help://DevExpress.NETv10.1/DevExpress.AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FindRowCellTemplateControltopic.htm) method.